# How to get Font Awesome Icon in react app for a pseudo element in css

Tags: css, reactjs, font-awesome

Following is my css file:

```
@import '~font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css';

.btn {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 100% 0 0 100% !important;
  height: 35px;
  width: 35px;
  font-size: 12px !important;
  background-color: white !important;
  color: dodgerblue !important;
  border-color: dodgerblue !important;
  transition: all 0.2s cubic-bezier(0.075, 0.82, 0.165, 1);
}

#add-btn.btn::after {
  position: absolute;
  font-family: 'Font Awesome 5 Free';
  content: '\f101';
  font-size: 15px;
}
```

And this is my jsx file.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Card, CardImg, CardText, CardBody, CardTitle, CardSubtitle, Button } from 'reactstrap';
// import 'font-awesome/css//font-awesome.min.css';
import './Books.css';

class BookCard extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="BookCard mx-auto">
        <Card>
          <div className="img-container">
            <CardImg src={this.props.book.imageUrl} />
          </div>
          <CardBody>
            <CardTitle>{this.props.book.title}</CardTitle>
            <CardSubtitle className="mb-2">{this.props.book.subtitle}</CardSubtitle>
            <div className="description">
              <CardText>{this.props.book.description}</CardText>
            </div>
            <div className="button-container">
              <Button id="add-btn">Add</Button>
            </div>
          </CardBody>
        </Card>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default BookCard;
```

In the css file above, I would like to insert a font awesome icon as a pseudo element of my button with id `add-btn`. The default class of the button element is `.btn` .

In the css file, I have tried it with this syntax `#add-btn.btn::after`, and this as well `.btn::after`.
And I have tried with importing `font-awesome.min.css` in the jsx file too, yet it is not giving me the icon. **Instead it is displaying a square**.

P.S I also tried importing it in the `index.js` file

Could anyone help me with this.

Answer (score 2):

**Nothing to do with React**

Bold fonts, won't show up until you put in the right `font-weight`

**Issue Example**

```css
.test {
  font-size: 5em;
}

.test:after {
  position: absolute;
  font-family: 'Font Awesome 5 Free';
  content: '\f101';
}
```

```html
<link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.0/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="test"></div>
```

**Fix**

Added `font-weight: 900;`

```css
.test {
  font-size: 5em;
}
.test::after {
  position: absolute;
  font-family: 'Font Awesome 5 Free';
  content: '\f101';
  font-weight: 900;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.0/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="test"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use font-awesome in css class **before** or **after**

**try this code:**

```
.class-name:before {
    font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free";
    font-weight: 400;
    content: "\f1ea";
    position:absolute;
    color:#ccc;
    top:0;
    right:0;
    font-size:25px;
    font-weight:500;
    z-index:-1;
    opacity:0.5;
}
```

if not working please make sure are you installed fontawesome library

**How install? [check here >>](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@fortawesome/react-fontawesome)**

Answer (score 0):

More Icons and more simple way with react-native elements.

You can also use **fontawesome** like described here:
https://reactnativeelements.com/docs/next/components/icon

**Example**: here you get an price-tag icon `️` before your text

```
import { Icon } from '@rneui/themed';

...

<View style={styles.iconWrapper}>
   <Icon name="tag" type="material-community" color="grey" size={12} />
   <Text style={styles.text}>YOUR TEXT</Text>
</View>

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
   iconWrapper: {
    display: 'flex',
    flexDirection: 'row',
   },
   text: {
    fontSize: 12,
    color: 'grey',
   },
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Use a SVG as a background image:

```
.angle-after:after {
  display: block;
  content: '';
  background-image: url('../../node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-pro/svgs/light/angle-right.svg');
  background-size: 28px 28px;
  height: 28px;
  width: 28px;
}
```